# User Impersonation race condition

Tags: c#, file-io, impersonation

I'm developing a winforms app that at a given point in time, impersonates a user and copy a file to a predefined and static network folder (by static I mean it's always in the same server).
This app will be used by few concurrent users at first but this might change. My concern here is that, 2 or more users impersonate the network credentials to write on the network share and write at the same time. Logic tells me that the windows server providing the share will notice that 2 write operations, performed by different machines, are providing the same credentials...

Should I be concerned in this case? I couldn't find relevant documentation on the topic...

Comment: Isn't the user impersonation aspect irrelevant here? Seems to me to be about concurrently writing to a shared drive.

Comment: @Baldrick I don't think so. If you "Think Security" accepting a write operation from 2 different IPs using the same credential... well... shaddy at least...

Comment: Don't think there's any issue with that. There's no rule against multiple computers being logged on and running as the same user. My laptop and desktop, and maybe a couple of servers at work, are all logged on as me. If I were to try to write to a commonly accessible location, there'd be no issue related to 'the same user connecting from different machines'. That is totally normal - nothing 'shady' about it.